# Google Cloud Speech not installing on Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech, grpcio

I've been trying to install the google speech api on my raspberry pi venv but it gets stuck while installing grpcio.

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
```

The Python version i'm using is 3.8.6.

I've tried to let it install overnight but the system was unresponsive and it didn't install. I've also tried installing wheels but it didn't fix the problem. CPU goes to 100% and crashes.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj1hD.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay before doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.